# POSTMAN - Send a request by already existing request name

Tags: javascript, postman

Is there any possibility to send a request explicity with some existing name's request?
In my collection we have some requests, GetLatestElement (for example).

Is it possible?

```
pm.sendRequest(GetLatestElement);
```

Regards,

Comment: Most searched and most needed feature. But POSTMAN does not provide this.

Answer (score 2):

```
  postman.setNExtRequest(Requestname)
```

https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/building-workflows/

use

```
postman.setNextRequest(null)
```

to stop postman collection runner from executing any more reqeust.

You can also use :

```
pm.sendRequest(pm.request)
```

you can store pm.request of any reqeust to a variable as
pm.variables.set("req",pm.request)

now you can execute it as:

```
pm.sendRequest(pm.variables.get("req"))
```